# Why is my boolean always true?

Tags: java, boolean

I made a class for a date and within this class lies the following declarations:

```
private int year;
private boolean leap = ((year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0));
public boolean isLeap() {return leap;}
```

And then (in a different file) within the main method:

```
String leapStr;
if (dateObject.isLeap()) {leapStr = "";}
else leapStr = "non-";
System.out.printf("Year %d is a %sleap year.", dateObject.getYear(), leapStr);
```

So, for some reason leapStr is never "non-", even when the year is clearly not a leap year. I have absolutely no idea what the problem could be. Any ideas?

Comment: Is year initialized? Instead of initializing `leap`, compute it in `isLeap()` or compute `leap` in the constructor.

Comment: You post only half of your code. The important part are missing. How do you initialize year?

Comment: if year is not initialized, it will have value = 0, so boolean leap will always be true, so paste complete code where you are initializing year.

Comment: `private boolean leap = ((year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))`. Insert the above mentioned code into the method isLeap()

Comment: Becaue this is not a spreadsheet. `leap` does not change magically whenever `year` changes.

Comment: @CyrilGandon Year is initialized in the constructor. I figured that `boolean leap` would automatically find out what year is, but I was wrong. So I put the formula for calculating the leap year in the `isLeap()` method and it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the value of leap is calculated once on object creation, and at that moment year is initialized with default value of 0.
You should calculate leap in isLeap method.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialized year hence the default value for int will be 0 , this is why yor condition is always returning true (0%400 == 0)